# Assigning track number to files added for remuxing with mkvmerge

Tags: bash, mkv

Given I have the following files:

- `Test.mkv`
- `Test.spa.srt` (codec would be S_TEXT/UTF8)
- `Test.eng.srt` (codec would be S_TEXT/UTF8)

And the `Test.mkv` file has the following tracks (with this format **{TRACK_ID(TRACK_NUMBER): CODEC (LANGUAGE)}**):

- 0(1): S_TEXT/ASS (spa)
- 1(2): V_MPEGH/ISO/HEVC (und)
- 2(3): A_AAC (jpn)
- 3(4): S_TEXT/ASS (eng)

I would like to remux all of it removing the current audio tracks (S_TEXT/ASS), adding the new ones (S_TEXT/UTF8) and reordering all the tracks to have the following output file `Test2.mkv`:

- 0(1): V_MPEGH/ISO/HEVC (und)
- 1(2): A_AAC (jpn)
- 2(3): S_TEXT/UTF8 (spa)
- 3(4): S_TEXT/UTF8 (eng)

For achieving it I am using the following command:

```sh
mkvmerge --quiet --output "Test2.mkv" --track-order 0:1,0:2,0:0,0:3 --video-tracks 1 --audio-tracks 2 --subtitle-tracks !0,3 "Test.mkv" --language 0:spa "Test.spa.srt"
--language 0:eng "Test.eng.srt"
```

The command remuxes everything fine and I achieve the goal but with one small issue: The track numbers are not sequential and there is a jump in the numbering because of the deletion of two tracks (that's my guess) so I get:

- 0(1): V_MPEGH/ISO/HEVC (und)
- 1(2): A_AAC (jpn)
- 2(5): S_TEXT/UTF8 (spa) <-- The track number should be 3, not 5
- 3(6): S_TEXT/UTF8 (eng) <-- The track number should be 4, not 6

Somehow I am missing the way to assign the track number to the files I am adding to the main container one (the mkv file) but cannot figure it out.

Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out!

The `Track Number` is given by the `--track-order` argument and the number of files added on top of it so that's why I am getting the skipping in the sequence.

While not adding explicitly the order of the two new tracks (the additional subtitle files with S_TEXT/UTF8) `mkvmerge` appends them to the end so the track order will be equal to:

```
--track-order 0:1,0:2,0:0,0:3,1:0,2:0
```

> Remember, the track order is [File Id:Track Id].

Then by adding as well `--subtitle-tracks !0,3` it removes the original subtitle tracks (S_TEXT/ASS) and therefore the track-order will be equal to the same `--track-order` but skipping the numbers of the Track Numbers 3 and 4.

**Conclusion**: `--track-order` should only include the tracks added to the remuxing and none that will be removed or the sequence will be altered.